# Where in BC, Canada is this?

Tags: canada, locate-this, tourism

[image: Image from advert]
This still was grabbed from an ad for traveling in BC.  This ad: [ExploreBC.com](https://youtu.be/JW0mH4AjUU8)

Can anyone identify where this was taken?

Comment: Presumably somewhere in British Columbia. Unfortunately that’s an area of almost one million square kilometres, a large fraction of which is covered in mountains and lakes. Nothing in this image appears to be particularly distinctive. I’d suggest your best option is to contact the body behind the campaign.

Comment: @ChrisH I thought someone might recognize the lodge and the lake combo since they are quite distinctive. :(

Comment: It's probably the most recognisable part, in the unlikely event somebody here is familiar with that particular lodge. But a lodge near a lake isn't unusual, nor is it something I'd consider distinctive (especially when it's not the focus of the image but only incidentally included, with extremely low detail visible).

Comment: Actually, it's not that distinctive. It's not Lake Garibaldi nor Whistler which I would have thought them to be on first impressions. I did ask the question under the YouTube video so if I'll get an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: It looks rather like a place I once visited in Alberta.

Comment: @phoog oooh - where in Alberta?... for the curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Mistaya Lodge](https://mistayalodge.com/location/) at 51.698736, -116.634464.
[image]

Did you try searching Google Image Search? I searched your pic on Google Image Search. I saw answer is result at bottom. I screen cap [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeb7cVBrzSc).

[image]

Comment: no problems!!! don't forget google image search.

Comment: LOL - I use it for bird and plant ID a lot but forgot about it for this.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass apology if i didn't google yellowstone park pic. i learned lesson and will do this going ahead. i just put my pics in my closed deleted questions into Google, i think you know what i mean. but google didn't identify and gave no result.

Comment: I couldn't find this on Google Image search... Please keep in mind the locations vary based on your own location; that's why I resorted to YouTube. Good research!

Comment: @gktscrk thanks! i never knew Google results vary based on your own location! no offense, and apology if i offended anyone. i said that so other people don't get downvoted and closed. i got downvoted and closed and critics because critics said I didn't Google.

Comment: Hello! Please write your opinion about the sockpuppets into the meta question! We need your opinion there. Thank you!

Comment: @guest Hi! I think it's more useful to discuss https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/when-where-in-the-world-is-overdone-or-collides-with-wanta#comment15617_6662 and whether my 6 questions were closed properly.

Comment: That would be useful too, but it would be also very useful and necessary that you talk aboit whether or not you use sockpuppets!!